# Problem with taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I created a "Science" category, which shows up at the bottom of the add content page. But I also created a "History" category and that doesn't show up. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for your question and welcome to Drupal SE. What do you mean that the science category shows up at the bottom of the add content page?

Comment: If I hit "add article," when I am filling out the article, there are tags and below it, the science category that I can fill in.

Comment: This isn't enough information. What did you build it to do?

Comment: First off, thanks for responding. I am rebranding a current website (www.yttwebzine.com). The new website will be studyhallrocks.com. It offers historical context to today's issues, science news and current events. I know it's important to get the categories right!  Right now, under "vocabulary name" in Taxonomy, I have: forums, history topics, news, science topics and tags. I'm hoping I've done the categorizing the right way. But when I add an article, I find a box at the bottom that says "science categories." I don't find one that says "history categories."

Answer (score 1):

The best I can interpret your question:

A "category" in this context is typically a Taxonomy. If you see the "Science" category when creating a node, that would mean there is a "term reference" field added to that content type.

If you do not see the "History" taxonomy options when adding new content, I would assume there is no term reference field on that content type to this taxonomy.

Add a new "Term Reference" field to this content type. Ensuring it is associated with the "History" vocabulary. Then when creating a new node of this type, you should see this field.

If this field is added to this content type, then I would double check your "form display" settings on the content type to ensure this field is available.